# Select box inside select and other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to do the following:

Having a select box,

```
<select name="some" id="some">
    <option value="xx">xx</option>
    <option value="yy">yy</option>
    <option value="ww">ww</option>
    <option value="zz">zz</option>
    <option value="uu">uu</option>
</select>
```

And when I select the option xx, open another select box

```
<select name="some_xx" id="some_xx">
    <option value="xx">xx</option>
    <option value="yy">yy</option>
    <option value="ww">ww</option>
</select>
```

Then, If I select in the some_xx the YY or WW or XX option it loads some html info ( a form ). ANd in the some select if I select the others options (not xx) it also loads some html info ( a form ).

All the forms are different, so I would like to load an external file with all the forms, is it possible? How to do all of this?

I know it will involve some javascript, but I really don't know how and I've searched quite a bit and seen some functions like `load()` and create selects but can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

edit: I have this code but it's not dynamic and it's not working right...

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
       function changeForm($(this)) {
            $('#form').load('$(this).html');
       }  

       function changeForm_xx($(this)) {
            $('#form2').load('$(this).html');
       } 

      $('#some').change(function() {
           changeForm($(this));
      });    
      $('#some_xx').change(function() {
           changeForm_xx($(this));
      });
});
</script>
```

And also, I want to remove the load content when I change the select

UPDATE: working: close

Comment: Ok here what I've done so far... can you help me? the

Comment: Too sketchy. Me no understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to like this. you have many errors in your script . see Demo : [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQqdK/)

Error List

1. `function changeForm($(this))` // here you added Extra parenthesis and as Jquery obj.
2. $`('#form2').load('$(this).html')` // this is wrong. you need to call as below . it is `yourObj.html()` method.

   ```
    function changeForm(obj) {
      var someVar= $(obj).html();
           $('#form').load(someVar); //here you perform load Operation. 

      }  

      function changeForm_xx(obj) {
         var someVar= $(obj).html();
           $('#form').load(someVar); //here you perform load Operation. 
      }

     $('#some').change(function() {
          changeForm($(this));
     });    
     $('#some_xx').change(function() {
          changeForm_xx($(this));
     });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to remove the selects and values when we change again ;)